# Magento : Layered Navigation on CMS Page is Only Filtering by 'Default Category'

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, attribute-set, cms-pages

I have a CMS page which displays products filtered by attribute (using 'Product List Plus' Magento extension widget).

I am trying to get layered navigation to display on this CMS page to be able to filter these products.

I have used below code which causes the layered navigation to appear:

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
<block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
</block>
</reference>
```

However this is only filtering products in uncategorised 'Default Category'.

I would like to filter results by a specific category.

Any ideas how to do this?